# how can we detect overspeeding through sensor or by building up circuit ??

Tags: arduino, sensor, gsm

I am working on project to detect overspeeding through sensor. 
but i am not getting any information regarding sensor.
All i want to do, sensor inside vehicle with arduino and gsm which will send out message to central monitoring unit consist of arduino and GSM.

Comment: Why don't you use a GNSS system such as GLONASS or GPS?

Comment: is there any alternative except gps???

Comment: GLONASS, BeiDou (北斗), Galileo? Or perhaps you could use OBD2 and tie into the vehicle's bus.

Comment: Hall effect sensor in a wheel?

Comment: I am not sure there is something for an onsensor, and you will have to maybe rely on a Wheel sensor(a hall effect) or an IR with bw strips on the wheel to measure the speed of the vehicle.

Comment: Thanks whats the programming code for gps to check overspeeding with arduino ?

Comment: "overspeeding" has two parts: knowing what the speed is, and knowing what the limit is.  The latter one may be tricky, except when exceeding the maximum limit applicable anywhere in the overall operating area.

Answer (score 1):

OBD2 has a standard messaging format and signalling protocol, and will likely be your best bet. It likely depends on the car, but the raw data you might get out is a voltage, or you can likely get a real speed value right from the engine ECU. This is how some US insurance companies collect information on their drivers to adjust their rates.

Your best bet is to access the ECU through OBD2, or if it is a car that uses CANbus, you can likely just buy something off the shelf for CANbus. As mentioned in previous comments, if you don't want to tinker with OBD or CAN, then use GPS or tap into the actual sensor in the drivetrain to get raw data you'd then have to calibrate to the proper speeds. OBD sounds much simpler to me. There are off-the-shelf devices that will do this for you, I suggest the "collaboration" route and figuring out how those work to simplify your progress.

Comment: My point is, the car already has the sensors you need, why not just use those to get the data you need to upload?

Comment: what sensors are you talking about ??

Comment: It varies from car to car, but often there is a sensor inside the transmission that sends rpm and gear ratio information to the engine computer, that then works out the speed of your vehicle.

Comment: Tapping into the sensor and using that data means you need to do more programming than just using the output from the engine computer through the OBD2 port

Comment: What's obd2 port?

Comment: In the US, it is required to be in the driver's seating area, but laws may be different elsewhere. http://nissanhelp.com/diy/maxima/projects/images/2005_nissan_maxima_obd_connector.jpg that is what it looks like

Comment: Nearly every car made after 1996 should have one